# Showing that the pmf of any two discrete random variables is given by the convolution of the individual pmf

Tags: probability, convolution

The question states:

> Show that the pmf of any two discrete random variables is given by the
> discrete convolution of the individual pmfs.

I'm confused because everything I've seen online assumes independence. I was also confused because shouldn't the question instead say "show that the *sum* of the pmf of any two discrete random variables is given by the discrete convolution of the individual pmfs."

Does the question make sense?

Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are discrete random variables then my solution is:

$Z=X+Y$

$$P(Z=z)=\sum_{x=-\infty}^{\infty}P(X=x,X+Y=z)=\sum_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} P(X=x, Y=z-x)=\sum_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} P(X=x)P(Y=z-x)=\sum_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} P(x)P(z-x)= \sum_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} p_x p_{y}(z-x)$$

Comment: (1) Yes, this assumes the variables are independent because it assumes that $p((X, Y) = (x, y)) = P(X = x) P (Y = y)$. (2) It should read "the pmf of the *sum* of any two distinct (and independent) rvs is given by the convolution of the individual pmfs".

Comment: Yep, I believe everything you said and you proof is correct. Just swap the places of the word sum and pmf in your quotes.